# Dbeaver не отображает данные таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

При попытке отобразить данные выпадает ошибка

Ошибка

SQL Error [08003]: No operations allowed after connection closed.
SQL Error [08003]: No operations allowed after connection closed. 
No operations allowed after connection closed. No operations allowed
   after connection closed. Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 114*770
   milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was
   1 milliseconds ago. Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 114*770
   milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was
   1 milliseconds ago. Software caused connection abort: recv failed
   Software caused connection abort: recv failed

**Вопрос**
Как избавится от ошибки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Аналогичная проблема озвучена в DBeaver WIKI: [MySQL (Amazon RDS) connections "expire" silently; further queries hang DBeaver #287](https://github.com/serge-rider/dbeaver/issues/287)

Предложенные варианты решения:

1. увеличить в настройках драйвера socketTimeout;
2. включить connection keep-alive;